# (newbie)Unable to run PHP with site using laravel framework

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I have got is developed site of PHP. Now My client want to extend some of the functionality of it, but whenever I am setting it up on my machine,and also after hosting to hostinger , I am getting below error:

```
Warning: require(/home/u364558673/public_html/../bootstrap/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u364558673/public_html/index.php on line 21

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/u364558673/public_html/../bootstrap/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php-5.5/pear') in /home/u364558673/public_html/index.php on line 21
```

Index.php: contains :

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/start.php';
```

Site Folder structure :

[image: root of site.]

Public_html :

[image]

Bootstrap Folder:

[image]

Please help me out. I wasted many days in googling. :(

Comment: you don't have `boostrap/autoload.php`

Comment: HI, thanks for the response, I checked, the file suggested is available..

Answer (score 0):

You need to go up two directories:

```
require __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/start.php';
```

Comment: Still same error :(
Warning: require(/home/u364558673/public_html/../../bootstrap/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u364558673/public_html/index.php on line 21

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/u364558673/public_html/../../bootstrap/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php-5.5/pear') in /home/u364558673/public_html/index.php on line 21